# How to detect the duplicate wmf files in docx file

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk, wmf, mathtype

There is a docx file which include some duplicate mathtype equations, If save it as a html file with Office, those equations can be converted to png files, and duplicate equations are converted to only one png file.

Now I want to detect the duplicate equations using open xml sdk 2.5, currently I can get file names of wmf (corresponding to those equations, uing ImagePart.Uri.OriginalString), but find no way to detect the equality.

I also tried the [method](https://github.com/papnkukn/wmf), check the CheckSum of each ImageData, for most of equations, it work; but for simple equations like "(", and ")", the CheckSum are the same.

I also tried to compare the two wmf files (corresponding to equations)' stream, but it will show difference even two complete same equations.